Understanding the dissociation constant of a ligand - receptor complex?
I am learning about dissociation constants in Lodish's Molecular Cell Biology and can't follow an example in the text - specifically, how he calculates [P] in the cell to be ~111x10^-10 M and the ratio to be 99% (text below). I feel like this example is supposed to be easy and that I am missing something super obvious. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Text Excerpt
"Typically, a protein’s binding to a specific DNA sequence exhibits a Kd of 10–10 M, where M symbolizes molarity, or moles per liter (mol/L). To relate the magnitude of this dissociation constant to the intracellular ratio of bound to unbound DNA, let’s consider the simple example of a bacterial cell having a volume of 1.5 × 10–15 L and containing 1 molecule of DNA and 10 molecules of the DNA-binding protein P. In this case, given a Kd of 10–10 M and the total concentration of the P in the cell (∼111 × 10–10 M, about a hundredfold higher than the Kd), 99 percent of the time this specific DNA sequence will have a molecule of protein bound to it and 1 percent of the time it will not, even though the cell contains only 10 molecules of the protein! Clearly P and D have a high affinity for each other and bind tightly, as reflected by the low value of the dissociation constant for their binding reaction. For protein-protein and protein-DNA binding, Kd values of ∼10–9 M (nanomolar) are considered to be tight, ∼10–6 M (micromolar) modestly tight, and ∼10–3 M (millimolar) relatively weak."
Link to Text

This is all just algebra and some basic chemistry, the author is giving you an equation and expecting you to be familiar with algebra and chemistry and use that knowledge to follow along with the equations.

a bacterial cell having a volume of 1.5 × 10–15 L and containing ... 10 molecules of the DNA-binding protein P

Concentration is molecules per volume: the volume is given, the  concentration is given. To go from molecules to molar, divide by Avogadro's number.
10 molecules/(1.5 * 10^-15 liters) * (1 Molar/(6.02214 * 10^23 molecules/liter)) = 1.11 * 10^-8 M = 111 * 10^-10 M

given a Kd of 10–10 M and the total concentration of the P in the cell ... 99 percent of the time this specific DNA sequence will have a molecule of protein bound to it and 1 percent of the time it will not

Kd = [P][D]/[PD]
If [P] ~= 100 * Kd, we can substitute for [P]:
Kd = 100 * Kd [D]/[PD]
Do some algebra: multiply both sides by [PD]/Kd
Kd * [PD]/Kd = (100 * Kd [D]/[PD]) * ([PD]/Kd)
cancel:
[PD] = 100 * [D]
The bound concentration [PD] is going to be 100 times the unbound concentration [D]. We've done some approximating to get there so might as well say roughly 1% as D and 99% as PD.

Thank you Bryan, that was a very helpful explanation (and yes, it's been a while since I took gen chem, I definitely need to review!)

@user123429 Probably also worth noting that, while you should be able to do the algebra, from a biology perspective we're usually more concerned with rough order of magnitude and a conceptual understanding. Here, you should be focused on understanding that when concentration of [P] is much larger than the Kd, that means most D will be bound with P as PD. If [P] = Kd, then only half of D will be bound as PD.
